# MenuLibre Removing Items from Whisker Menu

Tags: xfce, 18.10, menu, whisker, menulibre

I've seen some stuff on here for this, but no solid answers.

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 18.10. I wanted to change the category icon in the Whisker Menu for Wine. I checked the Whisker Menu properties, and the default for editing applications was MenuLibre.

So I installed MenuLibre, changed the icon, and saved it. When I closed MenuLibre and opened the Whisker Menu the new icon was there, but lots of the icons for other programs were now missing. I would like to find a way to get them to show up again.

I can see stuff online of people reporting this issue, but no good solution. Any solutions to this would be welcome, as it gets pretty tiresome having to launch some of my programs from the terminal...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Alacarte. I had the same issue. just run `sudo apt purge menulibre` in terminal and after that run `sudo apt install alacarte`. You will then find it as "main menu" in your whisker menu. Run it and click "Restore system configuration". Be sure to use Alacarte for menu editing to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: That did the trick! After logging out and logging back in I had to put some of those programs back in my favourites, but this worked. Thank you very much :)